# Can a USB key data be erased by a upsurge in the voltage?

Tags: voltage, usb-device, security

Say I want to design a USB key that would hold personal information. And I want to have a kill switch that would make the NAND memories just destroy or change status instantly by an upsurge of voltage.
There's any chance for that?
I've seen many "USB port destroyer" usb keys that simply increase the voltage at the USB port and burn it down.
Is there a way to use that same voltage increase but to burn the USB key or damage it enought to make the data inside the NAND cells unaccessible?

Comment: You need to clarify who your adversary is...who do you think is interested in your data? If it is the hacker kid next door you could get by with simply destroying the interface circuits. If you are worried about the NSA getting your data then you need to work harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enough voltage can damage a circuit, maybe enough that it's difficult or impossible to repair.

An easier and more reliable approach would be to encrypt the NAND data and have the switch simply delete the decryption key.  At that point the data is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for your input.